# How do I load custom CSS for a widget only when the widget is used?

Tags: css, widget

I have a custom widget for the product page (catalog product view). How can I load the custom CSS file into the head only when the Widget is actually placed on the page?

I am looking for a best practice method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use so xml instruction in your file xml for example **app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**:

```
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block after="-" name="header.styling.mobile"
                   template="Magento_Theme::html/header/custom-css.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="is_cms_block" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

and the code for **Magento_Theme::html/header/custom-css.phtml**:

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->hasIsCmsBlock()): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('css/styles.css'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

and if you have this block on page for example cms with url **yoursite.com/url/cms/page** your file will have location on  **Magento_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_id_url_cms_page.xml** you write:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.styling.mobile">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="is_cms_block" xsi:type="booleand">true</argument>
                </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```